# Sonarcloud covergare is not calculated

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-coverage

I am trying to configure sonarqube coverage for my project.

My pom file is as below, when I run mvn verify it creates jacoco.exec file in target directory and when I configure local sonar it shows the coverage, but in sonar cloud I my coverage is not calculated. What is the missing part in the following file

My other questions;

1. Do I need to configure jacoco.exec file location in sonar cloud.
2. What is the point of configuring jacoco in profile rather than plugin

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Backend</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <sonar.java.source>17</sonar.java.source>
        <checkstyle-maven-plugin.version>3.2.0</checkstyle-maven-plugin.version>
        <checkstyle-version>10.3.4</checkstyle-version>
        <maven-site.version>3.7.1</maven-site.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.8</jacoco.version>
        <jacoco.path>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</jacoco.path>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${basedir}/target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- Check style -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${checkstyle-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                            <version>${checkstyle-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-site.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${jacoco.path}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>checkstyle</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "exec" format is deprecated.  You should have the following properties:

```
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${basedir}/target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
    <jacoco.path>${basedir}/target/jacoco_report</jacoco.path>
```

I know that some documentation states that the jacoco.path value ends with "jacoco.exec", but I believe it is supposed to be the directory, and where the "xml" file is stored, not the "exec" file.

We've been using these settings for years.

Note that you should also verify that the build is producing these files. One good way to verify it is to look for the "index.html file in the "jacoco_report" directory and open that. It will show your coverage results, from jacoco's point of view (note that SonarQube's coverage computation algorithm is slightly different from Jacoco's).

Comment: I run "mvn clean verify " but it didnt created jacoco_report directory in the target folder.

Comment: Ok, then that confirms that this problem has nothing to do with sonarqube. Your plugin configuration has a problem. Did you change the jacoco.path property as I suggested?